# Error al eliminar elementos de ComboBox contenidos en una tabla de sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, combobox, tree

Estoy realizando un programa para el control de gastos. Tengo un error que no puedo encontrarle la vuelta al eliminar una categoría del combobox:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Comisión

```
    #Listado de categoría
    self.comboCateg=ttk.Combobox(self.ingresos, textvariable=self.categoria)
    self.comboCateg['values']=self.listaCateg()
    self.comboCateg.grid(row=2, column=1)
    

    #Función de eliminar categoría
def eliminarCateg(self):
    conexion=self.conectar()
    cursor=conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM cat_ing WHERE categoria="+ self.comboCateg.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Categoría","Categoría eliminada con éxito")
    conexion.commit()
    self.categoria.set('')
    conexion.close()
    self.listaCateg()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta hacer la consulta de esta forma

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM Table WHERE Columna = (?)", (params, ))
```

esto te puede interesar [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)

Comment: Lo había intentado antes y tampoco me había funcionado. Pero ahora está joya. Gracias genio.